# i have a text file in that text file some characters data . in that data there is no delimiter and no space

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

### example:

1).I have a text file in that text file some data.

### file .text

bhanuprathapkorem

2). i have table emp in hive in that table 3 columns.

### emp_table

```
select * from emp;
```

### output:

```
col1   col2     col3
----   -----    ----
bhanu  prathap  korem
```

how can i load the data file .text to hive emp table .
in that file there is no delimiter and no space .

Comment: Hint: RegexSerde or fix the process that creates that file

Comment: with out any logic it can be split there should be some logic for "bhanuprathapkorem" to make  "bhanu  prathap  korem"